# Onload popup javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a pop up load as soon as the page loads. I've used this already on the site and it works. However now nothing pops up.

```
<script>


window.onload = function (<?php echo $name . "," . $club ;?>){
                var txt = name + " has been deleted from this club";

                $.prompt(txt,{ 
                    buttons:{Delete:true},
                    close: function(e,v,m,f){

                        if(v){
                            var uid = f.userid;

                            window.location = "manageclub.php?id=" + club;                                  

                        }
                        else{}

                    }
                });
            }



</script>
```

Comment: Server side code in Javascript is BAD.

Comment: This makes NO  sense `function (<?php echo $name . "," . $club ;?>)` Look at the rendered code on the page, view the source.

Comment: @AshwinMukhija WTF are you talking about?  There is nothing wrong with running JavaScript serverside, and that doesn't even have anything to do with this question.

Comment: @Brad Exactly what I pointed out :)

Comment: @Brad Server-side != NodeJS in this case. I was referring to mingling server-side code into client side code.

Comment: Perhaps I am just being confused here but where is name coming from here? Looks like you create a function with whatever the name is going to be and the club like function ('john', 'boxing') {. Whats going on with the var txt = name?

Comment: @AshwinMukhija When done correctly there is nothing wrong with it, although this is a fine example of how to do it very incorrectly.  I think we're all in agreement.

Comment: I don't do much with PHP but wouldn't it be better to do a call onload to fetch the values used in the function and then just have this be a named function that has the values of name and club as arguments? Or if it is being rendered serverside I would think creating this as a named function then just calling it with the values would be better.

Comment: I fixed it - it was a error with referencing jquery files.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I should say that this approach doesn't feel quite right; you're building a new page just so that you can show a JavaScript prompt which will then redirect to another page ... I'm sure that could be done in a better way.

That said, here's the answer. You can't pass arguments inside the function definition like that; define those variables inside the function body instead;

Secondly, you're not escaping `club` properly for use in a URL.

```
window.onload = function ()
{
  var name = <?php echo json_encode($name) ?>,
  club = <?php echo json_encode($club) ?>,
  txt = name + " has been deleted from this club";

  $.prompt(txt, {
    buttons:{Delete:true},
    close: function(e,v,m,f) {
      if (v) {
        var uid = f.userid;

        window.location = "manageclub.php?id=" + encodeURIComponent(club);    
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I'm using [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to escape `club` properly inside JavaScript at the redirect code, and [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) to escape the PHP variables to be used in JavaScript.